# Oracle data pump using old data

Tags: oracle, datapump

I have an Oracle database that I am migrating data to a new server.

Everything is working perfectly, except that for some reason doing an exp uses data from the last time I ran it?

I have checked the timestamps of the dmp files and I am definitely using the new files to imp.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the data hasn't changed. How can we possibly answer this question.

Comment: The data has changed since then, I was just wondering if anyone had had a similar issue